# Java Email Address Validation

Tags: java, validation, email

How would I write a program that takes an email address typed in from the keyboard then loops through it looking for an @ sign to see if it has exactly one @ character before printing,  "valid," if the email address has one @ sign and "invalid," if the email address has more than one @?

Comment: See Scanner. And String.indexOf("@")

Comment: You forgot to ask a question...

Comment: What program would take an email address typed in from the keyboard then look for an @ to see if it has exactly one @ character in order to check if the email address is valid.

Answer (score 11):

Using the official java email package is the easiest:

```
public static boolean isValidEmailAddress(String email) {
   boolean result = true;
   try {
      InternetAddress emailAddr = new InternetAddress(email);
      emailAddr.validate();
   } catch (AddressException ex) {
      result = false;
   }
   return result;
}
```

(EDIT) Or simplified:

```
public static boolean isValidEmailAddress(String email) {
   try {
      new InternetAddress(email).validate();
   } catch (AddressException ex) {
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```